# When does static inner class get loaded into the JVM memory?

Tags: java

I was playing around some static nested class.

```
package com.tutorial; 
public class MyUpperClass {
    private MyUpperClass () {

    }
    private static class MyStaticInnerClass{
                private static final MyUpperClass muc = new MyUpperClass ();
    }
    public static MyUpperClass getInstance() {
        return MyStaticInnerClass.muc;
    }
}
```

When does `MystaticInnerClass` get loaded into the JVM memory?
At the time of, when `MyUpperClass` get loaded or `getInstance()` get called?

Comment: _static inner_ is contradictory. [_inner_ means non-static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: The fact that a class is a member of another class doesn't make any difference to when it is initialized.

Comment: Also, you may want to differentiate between loading and initializing (and clarify if you're asking about loading because the duplicate explains initializing).